# SharePoint 2013 Content Query Tool Part - How to format a "Date and Time" display field?

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, date-time, formatting

In the Content Query Tool, I'm pulling data from a task list, and for the Description, I want to display the Due Date. In the list itself, the Due Date is set to Date Only, Friendly Display Format (ex. November 1, 2016).

In the Content Query Tool, the Due Date is showing up as:

```
2016-11-01 00:00:00
```

I'm not quite sure why this is? I'm assuming it has something to do with the tool, but I can't figure out what. Is it changeable?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the content query webpart? If so, [here is a good example](https://sharepointuzma.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/content-query-web-part-date-format/) of how you can control the output of dates via xsl. Note that you'll have to adjust your schema, per the notes on the above page.

[Here is another example as well](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/).

Cheers, Matt